# $100$th derivative of $y=\ln(2x-x^2)$ at $x=1$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> What is $100$th derivative of $y=\ln(2x-x^2)$ at $x=1$?
>
> $a)2\times99!$
>
> $b)-2\times99!$
>
> $c)2\times101!$
>
> $d)-2\times101!$

I tried to find a pattern by calculating first derivatives of $y$:

$$y'=\cfrac{2-2x}{2x-x^2} ,\quad y'(1)=0$$

$$y''=\cfrac{-2(2x-x^2)-(2-2x)^2}{(2x-x^2)^2},\quad y''(1)=-2$$

And $y'''$is going to get really ugly. so I couldn't find any pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You split them first:

$$y = \ln(2-x) + \ln(x)\implies y' = \frac{1}{x-2}+\frac 1x\dots{}{} $$

Answer (score 2):

We can be a bit clever instead. Notice that

$$\ln(2x-x^2) = \ln(1-1+2x-x^2) = \ln(1-(x-1)^2)$$

$\ln(1-x)$ has a known Taylor series

$$-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$$

which means the Taylor series of $\ln(1-(x-1)^2)$ is

$$-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(x-1)^{2n}}{n}$$

Comparing terms to Taylor's theorem will give you that the answer is b.

Comment: I am not sure if "Be clever" is a nice thing to say. May I suggest "We can use this clever trick" or something like that?

Comment: @Levent is it better now? It's not meant to be a command, it's just a common phrase where I used to teach.

Comment: I am sure that is what you meant but still :)